# Retrieve annotations and propreties

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I have multiple `@groups({"group1","group2"})` annotations in my entities , I want to know if there is a way to retrieve the groups in order to use them .

i.e : An array of all the groups mentionned in a certain entity

Answer (score 0):

You must use the **SPL library PHP** for do this.
In particular the **reflectionClass**. It seems that has method for inspect all the DocBlock in class.

You can read this for more understand : [ReflectionClass::getDoccomment](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php)

for have a little idea of implementation you can inplement this kind of code :

```
function getAnnotations($class)
{       
    $inspectedClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
    $inspectedClassDoc = $inspectedClass->getDocComment();
}
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try that

Comment: I'm trying this atm http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadata.html